# If statement for drop down list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I have two drop down lists in my code where the data is retrieved from a SQL table.

I can't figure out an IF statement to show an error message if both of these two drop down lists have not been selected. I have added a list item in to tell the user to select a date/time.

I tried an if statement but this would not work.

If Statement:

```
    If DropDownList2.SelectedValue And DropDownList3.SelectedValue = Nothing Then

        warninginfo.Visible = True
    Else
        Response.Redirect("ConfirmationBooking.aspx")

    End If
```

Code:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Time" DataValueField="Time"  AppendDataBoundItems="True" width="162px" Height="31px">
    <asp:ListItem>-- Please Select a Time --</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Date" DataValueField="Date" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="162px" Height="30px">
    <asp:ListItem>-- Please Select a Date --</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Try `DropDownList2.SelectedValue Is Nothing And DropDownList3.SelectedValue Is Nothing`

Comment: So do both have to have something selected or can one of the fields not be selected? I mention this because if `DropDownList2.SelectedValue Is Nothing And DropDownList3.SelectedValue Is Nothing` then it would still pass if one of them didn't have anything selected. Better solution would be `DropDownList2.SelectedValue Is Nothing AndAlso DropDownList3.SelectedValue Is Nothing`...

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is wrong.  It should be (changed the AND to Or)

```
If DropDownList2.SelectedValue Is Nothing Or DropDownList3.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
```

Another option is to make those two fields required using a RequiredFieldValidator.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqFavoriteColor" Text="(Required)"
     InitialValue="none" ControlToValidate="DropDownList2" Runat="server"
 />
```